# What is libelli doing in Catullus 1

Tags: classical-latin, catullus

In Catullus 1 we have:

> Quare habe tibi quidquid hoc libelli,
>   qualecumque, quod, o patrona virgo,
>   plus uno maneat perenne saeclo.

I am not sure what *libelli* is doing.

Without it, I would put *hoc* in the subjunctive clause and translate as:

> Hence, have for yourself, whatever, of whatever kind, so that, to the patrona virgo, this endures more than one generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Libelli* is in the [**genitive of quantity**](http://www.orbilat.com/Languages/Latin/Grammar/Syntax/Syntax-Cases-Genitive.html), used after a noun of quantity to specify "of what." In addition to strict quantities like *libra* ("pound"), Latin uses this genitive with indefinite quantities, often "substantivized adjectives or pronouns in accusative or nominative," e.g. *quid*, *multum*, *plus*, *nihil*, etc.

A classic example of this construction is: "Quid novi?" = "What's new?" (lit.: "What of new?")

Here is an example from Cicero that uses *quidquid*:

> **quicquid malefici, sceleris, caedis** erit, proprium id Rosciorum esse debebit. (Cic. Rosc. Am. 42, 122)
>
> <sup>**Whatever evildoing, crime, or violence** there is, the Roscii surely will have a hand in it.</sup>

Here's a translation broken up into parts:

> *Quare, habe tibi* - "Therefore, please accept..."
> *quidquid hoc libelli* - "...whatever book this is..."
> *qualecumque* - "...as it is."